# Measure a tennis racquet grip size

Tags: tennis, racket, grip

I have an old aluminum tennis racquet that I'm looking to replace after having broke its strings. I know neither my hand's grip size nor the racquet's grip size, but I do know that the racquet is the right size for my hand. I looked up methods for measuring my hand's grip size, but I didn't find them to work well for me. However, if I can measure my old racquet, I'll be all set for getting a new one.

How can I measure the racquet grip size?

Comment: You say you're looking to get a new racquet - pretty much every racquet made today is produced in a number of different grip sizes. Do you have access to a tennis shop where you can go in and find out what size of grip best suits your hand size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://protennistips.net/tennis-racquet-grip-size/) has what you are looking for.

Essentially the grip size is the circumference of the octagonal section of the handle.  So just take a piece of string wrap around your old racquet and then measure the length of one string's worth around.'s

The article goes into depth on this, but a rule of thumb is the proper grip size allows you to comfortably grip the handle and be able to just fit your other hand index finger between the thumb and fingers of your grip hand.